# Possibility to create .dll from existing .exe source code project in c#?

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, exe, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible with 'same C# source code used to create a windows form app .exe' to generate .dll file?

This app .exe file uses C# native dll f.e., Hello.dll's classes to show User interface.

I have a class and few methods in app .exe like TreeView, refreshData, LoadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) and so on.

I would like to use its app.dll library classes in Matlab.

Please help.

Comment: Just create new project having type "class library" in Visual Studio, copy the sources you need into this project and build it.

Comment: You can refer to exe like a dll in another project, I dont know about matlab

Comment: Andy is right, the best practice is transfer the shared code to a class library dll

Comment: Use [`NET.addAssembly`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/net.addassembly.html) to load and use your assembly** types in matlab ... **: Assembly can be the .exe directly or .dll (but obviously using a dll to share code is cleaner) ... Here some simple example to instanciate a basic winform in matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/616-how-to-create-windows-forms-in-matlab

Comment: I made it , but i cannot access nested dll's contents into matlab, thanks all for the help.